# Unresolved method in WebStorm (discord.js, code works)

Tags: node.js, webstorm, discord.js

I'm wrapping my head around this. Autocompletion does not work `.then(r => { HERE })` either.

Kinda starting out with this and would be way easier if it just works (works outside of the promise).

Code runs without any problems as well. `delete` method is recognized as well but not at that part.

I have this problem in a bigger project as well and it gets me confused.

Trying to find something on the web for a few hours, but couldn't find anything that helps me out. Hope I wasn't blind at some point :P

Whole test source:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === 'test'){
        message.channel.send('something').then(r => r.delete(5000));
    }
});
```

Problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete command triget message you can use

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
    client.on("message", message => {
        if (message.content === 'test'){
            message.channel.send('something') 
            message.delete(1000)
            .catch(console.error)
        }
    });
```

If you use need to delete response message after some time you code must work, but you can try use reply method.

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === 'test'){
        message.reply('somethink')
        .then(msg => {
            msg.delete(10000)
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Maybe problem in you discord.js version? In v.12 version you need use 
`msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })`

Comment: The problem is not that the code doesn't work, its more about the IDE, in your code same thing: `Unresolved function or method delete()` (reported by webstorm) but everything works the way it should. its more a problem with intellisense

Answer (score 0):

Just means webstorm can't discern what functions the object will have after the promise resolves. This is because the [message create action](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js) in discord.js has multiple return types. So it's possible for the message object not to be passed into r, for instance in the event that the message failed to send, possibly by trying to send a message to a channel without the proper permissions.

If you add a check to confirm that r is the same type as message before trying to call .delete() I believe the warning will go away.

You can observe the potential error this highlight is warning you of by removing the bots permission to send messages in a channel, then by sending "test" to that same channel.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the error recently and having found a solution, if for example you want a text channel, by doing a get you can have a text or a voice . so check if the channel instance `TextChannel` (for my example)

```js
let channel = client.guilds.cache.get(process.env.GUILD_ID).channels.cache.get(config.status_channel);

if (channel instanceof TextChannel) {
  await channel.messages.fetch()
}
```