# Unresolved function or method send(), even if everything works ( WebStorm, discord.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js, webstorm

I’m trying to create a bot with WebStorm using Node.js

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require( "discord.js" )
const client = new Discord.Client(
    {
        intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]
    }
)

client.login( "token" )

client.on( "ready", () => {
    console.log( "Discord bot is online." )
} )

client.on( "messageCreate", ( message ) => {
    if( message.content === "!ph" ){
        message.channel.send( "hello" )
    }
} )
```

Even if everything works, in the event "messageCreate" when I do message.channel.send() the ide gives me this warning: "Unresolved function or method send() " suggesting me to create the send method. Does anyone know how to fix it, because they don’t recognize the method but then running it works anyway? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix WebStorm warning "Unresolved function or method" for "require" (Firefox Add-on SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136714/how-can-i-fix-webstorm-warning-unresolved-function-or-method-for-require-fi)

Comment: No, that didn’t solve my problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: @FrankLioty No, I haven't been able to fix the problem yet. Please vote up this thread to draw more attention to the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75241201/17083299 This answer worked for me. Maybe it does for you?